# lxc-checkpoint fails with ambiguous error message

Tags: linux, containers, iptables, lxc

The creation of a checkpoint is not successful and the error messages do not help me.
What am I doing wrong?

```
sudo lxc-create -t download -n bionic (`ubuntu`, `bionic`, `amd64`)
sudo lxc-start -n bionic -d
```

`sudo lxc-checkpoint -n bionic -D /tmp/cp` fails with:

```
lxc-checkpoint: bionic: criu.c: do_dump: 1328 dump failed with 1
lxc-checkpoint: bionic: criu.c: do_dump: 1342 criu output: Will skip in-flight TCP connections

lxc-checkpoint: bionic: tools/lxc_checkpoint.c: checkpoint: 200 Checkpointing bionic failed
```

#### dump.log:

```
iptables-restore: invalid option -- 'w'
ip6tables-restore: invalid option -- 'w'
Warn  (criu/fsnotify.c:283): fsnotify:  Handle 0x1b:0xc46 cannot be opened
Error (criu/irmap.c:86): irmap: Can't stat /no-such-path: No such file or directory
Error (criu/fsnotify.c:286): fsnotify:  Can't dump that handle
Error (criu/cr-dump.c:1352): Dump files (pid: 6126) failed with -1
iptables-restore: invalid option -- 'w'
ip6tables-restore: invalid option -- 'w'
Error (criu/cr-dump.c:1709): Dumping FAILED.
```

## Required information

- `uname -a`: `Linux bionic 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `lxc-start --version` : `3.0.3`
- Github issue: https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/3521

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by `iptables-restore` missing option `-w` in v1.6.1.
See [iptables issues for Ubuntu 18.04 #551](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/issues/551#issue-357657418) and [iptables-restore is missing -w option](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iptables/+bug/1791958)  for more info.

An option would be to compile iptables-restore 1.6.2 yourself.